# Could someone help me with my bash script that copies contents of a directory and pastes it to multiple servers?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a script that copies the contents of a directory. This directory contains drivers organized by computer model name. I would like to be able to update my main node (drop edited cab files) and have its entire content sent to multiple servers on the network. I have this working now, however its copying over everything in the main directory. I only want updated directories. Is there a way I can do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#source directory
source_directory="/images/drivers"

#remote username
remote_user="username"

#array of remote server IPs
remote_servers=("10.xx.xx.xxx" "10.xx.xx.xxx")

#Destination directory on remote servers
destination_directory="/images/drivers"

#specify the user and group ownership for the copied directories
ownership="name:name"

#Loop through each remote server and copy the contents
for server in "${remote_servers[@]}"; do
        rsync -avs --ignore-existing --chown="$ownership" "$source_directory/" "$remote_user@$server:$destination_directory/"
done
```

Comment: There are network configuration management and software deployment tools that automate this and more, I suggest you use one of these instead of rolling your own ad hoc scripts like this.

Comment: It seems like this quesiton could be boiled down to: "Is there a way to tell `rsync` to only copy the directory structure, not the files?" Is that right? If so, this isn't a programming question, it would be more appropriate to [unix.se]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this is not a good first question. Firstly, SO is for [programming questions only](/help/on-topic), but this seems to be essentially about rsync, which is not really a programming tool. You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead or [unix.se], but first please take [their tour](//askubuntu.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Secondly, ["Can someone help me?" is not a useful question here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), and I think they'd say the same on [ubuntu.se], so please write a better title; see [ask].

Comment: Oh, another alternate site option is [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `"` for ownership variable.
And the `--ignore-existing` flag is currently set, which means files that already exist on the receiver side will not be overwritten.

Use `--checksum` or `-c` flag with rsync.
Use `--delete` flag to delete extraneous files from destination directories. Use this if you want to keep the destination strictly in sync with the source directory, meaning if you delete a file in the source, it will also be deleted in the destination.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Source directory
source_directory="/images/drivers"

# Remote username
remote_user="username"

# Array of remote server IPs
remote_servers=("10.xx.xx.xxx" "10.xx.xx.xxx")

# Destination directory on remote servers
destination_directory="/images/drivers"

# Specify the user and group ownership for the copied directories
ownership="name:name"

# Loop through each remote server and copy the updated contents
for server in "${remote_servers[@]}"; do
    rsync -avs --checksum --chown="$ownership" "$source_directory/" "$remote_user@$server:$destination_directory/"
done
```

Keep in mind that using the `--checksum` flag can be CPU intensive, especially for large directories. So, test thoroughly before deploying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the missing quote was a typo in the question, so I fixed it. Otherwise the script wouldn't work at all, instead of working incorrectly.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [answer] if you want tips.